# node-gyp link library dependencies at build time

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

My `nodejs` addon uses `cares` library and my `binding.gyp` has `dependencies` attribute which is pointing to this. Now whenever I have to run `addon`, I have to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

Is there a way I can configure this in `binding.gyp` so that every time I don't have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. (Linking at build time)

Dependency setting in binding.gyp: `"dependencies": [ "deps/cares/cares.gyp:cares" ]`

Ex export: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=build/Release`

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16216870/1938163

Comment: @MarcoA. Yes it is. I tried `libraries` -L option with both relative and absolute path but no luck :(

Comment: This is the error message I am getting: `Library not loaded: @rpath/cares.dylib`

Comment: On Mac `"libraries": [ "-rpath ./build/Release/" ]` worked for me but strangely its not working on Linux(Ubuntu). Error message: `unrecognized command line option rpath`. Is there any alternative for rpath in Linux..?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`"libraries": [ "-Wl,-rpath,./build/Release/" ]`

Worked for me on Mac as well as Linux(Ubuntu).

Comment: Better one `"libraries": [ "-Wl,-rpath,<!(pwd)/build/Release/" ]`. This will work even when I do install with npm.(automatically sets the absolute path by executing pwd) but would not work on Windows. Strangely pre defined variable `PRODUCT_DIR` didn't work for me. `"libraries": [ "-Wl,-rpath,<(PRODUCT_DIR)" ]`

Comment: try `-Wl,-rpath,<(module_root_dir)/build/Release/` instead of the `<!(pwd)...`

Answer (score 8):

My answer to [how to add dependence to static library in binding.gyp node-gyp for node.js extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748224/how-to-add-dependence-to-static-library-in-binding-gyp-node-gyp-for-node-js-exte/40222639#40222639) seems to apply here as well, and should be cross platform.

In short it uses the `module_root_dir` and builds an absolute path.
Example:

```
"libraries": [
    "-lcares",
    "-L<(module_root_dir)/build/Release/"
]
```

Comment: This helped me fixed my problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have had success obtaining a relative path in Ubuntu & Debian using the following `binding.gyp` line:

```
"libraries": [ "../lib/somelib/somelib.a" ]
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
|--binding.gyp
|--app.cc
|--lib
   |--somelib
      |--somelib.a
```

I got the method (somewhat indirectly) from here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/49